# Running unit tests in Kotlin is not deterministic

Tags: kotlin

I am playing around with Kotlin by implementing a quick sort for an array of integers. The implementation class is

```
enum class SortingCriterion {
    DESCENDING, ASCENDING
}

class Program(
    private val data: Array<Int>,
    private val sortingCriterion: SortingCriterion = SortingCriterion.ASCENDING
) {

    fun run() = sort(data.copyOf())

    private fun sort(data: Array<Int>): Result {

        if (data.size < 2) {
            return Result(data)
        }

        val pivot = chooseRandomPivot()
        val less = data.asSequence().filter { e -> e < pivot }.toList().toIntArray().toTypedArray()
        val greater = data.asSequence().filter { e -> e > pivot }.toList().toIntArray().toTypedArray()

        return if (sortingCriterion == SortingCriterion.ASCENDING)
            Result(sort(less).data + pivot + sort(greater).data)
        else Result(sort(greater).data + pivot + sort(less).data)
    }

    private fun chooseRandomPivot() = data[data.indices.random()]
}
```

As you can see that I introduce the class `Result` wraping the sorting result. With that I can do the assert equals on expected `Result` and actual `Result`. The `Result` class is

```
class Result(val data: Array<Int>) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Result

        return data.contentEquals(other.data)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return data.contentHashCode()
    }
}
```

And the tests

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import kotlin.test.Test

class ProgramTest {

    @Test
    fun sort_data_in_default_order() {
        val actualResult = Program(arrayOf(1, 5, 4)).run()
        assertEquals(Result(arrayOf(1, 4, 5)), actualResult)
    }

    @Test
    fun sort_data_in_ascending_order() {
        val actualResult = Program(arrayOf(1, 5, 4), SortingCriterion.ASCENDING).run()
        assertEquals(Result(arrayOf(1, 4, 5)), actualResult)
    }

    @Test
    fun sort_data_in_descending_order() {
        val actualResult = Program(arrayOf(1, 5, 4), SortingCriterion.DESCENDING).run()
        assertEquals(Result(arrayOf(5, 4, 1)), actualResult)
    }
}
```

My problem is: The test results are not deterministic. By not deterministic, that means sometimes all the tests are passed, but sometimes one of them is failed! One of the example of failing test

```
expected: <Result@87a1> but was: <Result@10709e>
Expected :Result@87a1
Actual   :Result@10709e
<Click to see difference>

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <Result@87a1> but was: <Result@10709e>
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
```

Is there any wrong with my implementation?

Comment: First of all I would suggest to implement `Result.toString()` which outputs the contents of `data`, so we can see what is the problem. You can also make `Result` a data class and then you don't need your custom `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Also, what about items equal to pivot? I think you need to use either `e <= pivot` or `e >= pivot`, because otherwise you remove duplicated items.

Comment: hi @broot , good catch! That's a bug I have not covered yet :-D